# Spring Test + Mockito.mock - Spring fails because it tries to load the mocked bean @Autowired dependencies

Tags: spring, mockito, testng, spring-test

I can't find out why the following simple scenario is failing: I have a Spring application with a filter that loads a Spring bean from the application context:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter{

    private IPermissionService permissionService;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext ac = null;
        try{
            ac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(filterConfig.getServletContext());
            permissionService = ac.getBean(PermissionServiceImpl.class);
```

PermissionServiceImpl has an @Autowired attribute dataSource so in my TestNG test, I mock it in the Spring applicationContext:

```
@Configuration
public class MyFilterSpringTestConfig{

    @Bean
    public IPermissionService permissionService(){
        return Mockito.mock(PermissionServiceImpl.class);
    }
```

MyTest:

```
@Test
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyFilterSpringTestConfig.class)
public class MyFilterSpringTest extends BaseSpringFilterTest{

   ...
```

The problem is that on Spring initialization I get an exception complaining that PermissionServiceImpl's dataSource dependency is not satisfied. Since I wrapped it with a mock, why is it still failing? How could I fix it?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=myDataSource)}
```

Comment: Don't mock the class, mock the interface. If you create a mock of a class it is still an instance of that class with all the variables and annotations with it, which in turn are still scanned. So you should be mocking the interface (and also be programming to interfaces and not concrete classes as you do now).

Comment: You're right about mocking the interface. However in this case there are going to be two filters: Filter1 for PermissionServiceImpl and Filter2 for PermissionServiceImpl2. The dev has to define the filter that they prefer in web.xml and import the matching spring context for either PermissionServiceImpl  or PermissionServiceImpl2, depending on the filter. Using `permissionService = ac.getBean(PermissionServiceImpl.class);` in the filter helps assure they didn't import the wrong xml

Comment: Then what is the use of the interface... Use profiles or another way of wiring or create 2 interfaces, why do you need 2 implementations of the same interface and 2 filters? Seems like something wrong in the first place with that setup. Feels like you are trying to build something in, that you shouldn't be doing in the first place...

Comment: Yeah, I know it's messy. We have to support some legacy stuff not related to the problem (the filters also support non spring initialization etc. etc. etc). I'll forget about mocking the implementations (and rely on the developers reading the documentation). Anyway if you anwer about the impossibility of mocking implementation classes I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can perfectly mock class, but Springs mechanism will still detect the annotations because they are still instances of that class with all the information in it. Either don't use auto wiring and remove the annotation (then nothing is scanned) or use the interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When mocking a class using Mockito (or any other mocking framework) that class is still an instance of the original class. With that comes that it also contains all the annotations and class information with it.

So when you create a mock of the class it still detects all annotations on it and tries to full fill that. I.e. `@Autowire` other instances.

Either don't use auto wiring or don't mock the class but the interface (which doesn't contain that information).